# Which way can i transffer the json that posted to my Flask server webhook to java application that runs this server

Tags: java, python, spring, flask

Hello guys i'm new in python, i have java app that runs python script with flask server, which way can i transfer json posts that come to me to this java app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to redirect the incoming request to your java app. You might consider using a framework mentioned in [this article](https://jaxenter.com/integrating-python-with-java-170663.html).